# .pop and .push are not working properly when I use .pop, the app doesn't return me to the home screen.dart

Tags: flutter, firebase, push, routemaster

I m creating my own app but I m using this video like a guide to teach me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8Sx7wGiY-s&t=167s.
The thing is that I have a drawerlist.dart:

```
ListTile(
      leading: const Icon(Icons.help),
      title: const Text('Sugestão'),
      onTap: () {
        Routemaster.of(context).push('/sugestoes');
      },
    ),
```

This take me to the suggestion.dart, in this screen the user can do a suggestion and I save it in the firebase. So I have a suggestionRepository.dart,
suggestionController.dart,
in the suggestionController.dart, I have this function:

```
void createSugestao(String sugestaotexto, BuildContext context) async {
state = true;
final uidutilizador = _ref.read(userProvider)?.uid ?? '';

SugestaoModel sugestao = SugestaoModel(
    uid: uidutilizador, sugestaousuario: sugestaotexto, likes: 0);

final res = await _sugestoesRepository.createSugestao(sugestao);
state = false;
res.fold((l) => showSnackBar(context, l.message), (r) {
  showSnackBar(context, "Sugestão enviada com sucesso!");
  //Routemaster.of(context).pop; // mandar para a pagina de mostrar sugestoes
});
```

}

`"Routemaster.of(context).pop;"` ->  this piece of code should take me back to the homescreen right?? I tried to mode this piece of code to the suggestion.dart after the fuction is call and nothing happens. I did a print on the function and this was the output:
I/flutter ( 2687): Closure: ([Y0?]) => Future from Function 'pop':.

Other thing is I have a button on suggestion.dart that takes me to the                      `Routemaster.of(context).push('/visualizar_sugestoes');`.  When I m in the VisualizarSugestao.dart and I use the button on the appbar to go back I go straight to the homescreen.dart and I wanted to fo back to the suggestion.dart.